# How can I represent an attribute which is a multidimensional array in UML?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am designing a new project in UML and I need a multidimensional array as attribute of one of my classes (Figure below)

[image: Example of class with multidimensional array as attribute]

Right now I have put List of List to make everyone understand which are my purposes, but this is incorrect in standard UML. What should I do?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not illegal, though a bit language specific. Obviously it's plain text (since there's a superfluous ")" inside the expression). If you want to make this language independent you can design it this way:

[image]

Note that the dot says the role is an owned attribute in the class on the other side. So I also pulled out the `conditions` and put it in an association to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, depending on what you are wanting to represent. If you want to keep with templates then there is UML syntax to support that (a dash-line box overlaying the top-right of a Class allows you to represent template parameterisation). So you could specify a List template class that way, which you can then parameterise as the type for ‘actions’ (in UML this type is called a ‘bound element’). There are a few ways to represent bound elements, but UML does allow the c++ syntax using `Foo<T>` like you have. So something like `actions: List<string>[0..*]` would indicate multiple instances of attribute ‘actions’ each of which is a `List<string>`. You could alternatively specify actions in the way you have `actions: List<List<string>>`, which is one ‘actions’ attribute. Another way would be to define a regular Class which encapsulates the structural logic of your array, and type ‘actions’ with that. I have not seen syntax like `actions: string[0..*][0..*]`, but I’ll look it up and find out if UML supports it.

Comment: If I could use something like `actions: string[0..*][0..*]` it would be great since I would like to keep the diagram as simple as possible.

Comment: Sadly I can't find anything in the UML spec about having two or more dimensions to the multiplicity, it looks like its linear. The options are single integer, comma-separated list of integers, and range of integers specified with "..". You can add constraints like {unique} and {ordered} but that doesn't help you. You might be stuck then with actions: List<string>[0..*] or to specify as a class structure a-la Mr Killan's post.